# How to save uploaded files from a jquery clone contact form 7 field to media library?

Tags: php, jquery

already got a code in my function.php with wpcf7_before_send_mail

Code structure below:

```
<form action="#">
        // source table
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <table id="source-table" class="table">
               //...table elements here
            </table>
            <input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="clone-table">Clone table</a>

        // clone table 
        <div class="table-wrapper-1">
            <table id="clone-table" class="table-1">
                //...table elements here
            <input type="file" name="file-upload-1" id="file-upload-1" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

I've been posting this in wordpress stackexchange and it is put on hold as this is not for-front wordpress related.

And I've been googling this. Any hints is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Jerodev for your comment, I got those code above. I have a contact form 7 that has a table for the data and an input type file which will be cloned if the user decides. I got problem capturing the file uploaded from the cloned input type file.

Comment: Here's the scenarios.

1. source table with input type file
2. clone table 1 with input type file
3. clone table 2 with input type file

All clone is done through jquery.

contact form 7 treated those as only one even though I was able to change the id, class and name of the input file.